# Statistics Proof/set therory Question

Tags: probability, statistics

If $A\subset B$, show that

(a) $P(A^c\cap B) = P(B) - P(A)$

(b) $P(A)\leq P(B)$

All we were told was that $A\subset B$  and to use the partition theorem. How would one go about proving either? I think I have solved the first part, but not very sure, the second part is still a mystery to me.

Thanks.

Comment: Thanks, just fixed it, don't know how I overlooked that

Answer (score 1):

$(a)$
Since $A\subset B$, we have that $B=A\cup(A^c\cap B)$. This is the union of disjoint sets and therefore
$$
P(B)=P(A)+P(A^c\cap B).
$$
$(b)$
$$
P(B)=P(A)+P(A^c\cap B)\ge P(A)
$$
since $P(A^c\cap B)\ge0$.

Comment: Thank you!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!